# $('.classitem').submit(function(event){event.preventDefault}) doesn't work

Tags: html, jquery, forms

I'm a little curious.  I'm trying to use:

```
$('.comment').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
```

it keeps reloading the page on submit.
The form class is '.comment' and the button is type='submit'

Is the fact that I'm sourcing the form through a class a problem?

Comment: Are you calling this bind after jQuery is ready? (hint: wrap it all inside a `$(function(){ // });` block.)

Comment: Yeah, it's encapsulated in $( document ).ready(function()...

Comment: Then please post the full relevant HTML and JS, as it's not evident from just what you have here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buttons don't have `submit` events. The listener will never trigger.

```js
$('.comment').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button class="comment">submit</button>
</form>
```

`submit` is only a thing on `<form>`s, not on descendants of the form. So, call `preventDefault` on the `submit` event on the form.

```js
$('form').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <button class="comment">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear.  The form class is '.comment' and the button is type='submit'

Comment: Can you post the HTML markup in the question? If the form is the `.comment`, your code should work fine